# Why does the p-value of a composite null hypothesis have a supremum attached it?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

I noticed that there is a definition of the p-value in my textbook. It is defined as the p-value of a composite null hypothesis and it says the following:

[image]

I have no idea why it is written with a supremum. I've spent hours pondering this, does anyone have enough of a background to help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't understand the answer

Comment: The correct response to that is not to ask a new question, unless it substantively differs from the old one. You can ask the answerer a followup question in comments, and they may respond, or you can edit your question to clarify what you need (including what you didn't understand). Finally, you can wait two days from when you posted and then promote your question via a bonus, which will give it special prominence for a week, greatly increasing the chance of additional answers (you'll want to choose a bonus category that relates to the outcome you want), at the cost of 50 reputation.